# SQL SELECT Union SELECT FROM (Select...)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with a view, and can't use temp tables. Is it possible to :

> SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table 3)

I realize its bad coding practice select *, I'm just using it as an example. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, that should work assuming that table1 and table3 have columns with the same data types in the same order

Comment: One thing to note is that unless you are trying to remove duplicates you may want to use Union All. With just the Union you are taking the hit of having the query also do a merge join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That query parses as:

```
(SELECT * FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table 3))
```

In SQL Server, this will return a missing alias error.  So, add in the alias:

```
(SELECT * FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table 3) t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

if there has same count's of columns.. it will work

or try to these code

```
SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2 FROM TABLE1 A 

UNION 

SELECT B.COL1, B.COL2 FROM (SELECT C.COL1, C.COL2 FROM TABLE3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why you need to wrap it in a subquery, isn't it possible to do it directly<

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3
```