# SELECT from SELECT in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working in small food depot where we preparing deliveries for small shops. We using WMS to get our work done. For some reasons i need to get some data from database using SQL builder in system. So the case is.

To get information to which store particular product has been despatched I'm using this query:

```
select cd.cage_nbr, cd.units_of_product, pk.to_store
from cage_dtl cd
inner join item_master im on im.sku_id=cd.sku_id
INNER JOIN pkt_hdr pk ON pk.pkt_ctrl_nbr=cd.pkt_ctrl_nbr
where im.barcode = '105683004'
and cd.open_cage_batch = 31102014
```

To see list of stores and quantities of product allocated by our customer i'm using this query:

```
select sd.to_store, sd.alloc_qty, sd.alloc_batch, im.size_desc
from store_distro sd
inner join item_master im on im.sku_id=sd.sku_id
where im.barcode = '105683004'
and sd.alloc_batch = 31102014
```

But i need a SQL to show me any stores to which product has not been despatched.
I will appreaciate any help

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Oracle but i don't have access to database only through system where i can place SQL

Answer (score 2):

You can probably try doing a `LEFT JOIN` for your first query and check for `NULL`. Something like

```
select cd.cage_nbr, cd.units_of_product, pk.to_store
from cage_dtl cd
left join item_master im 
on im.sku_id = cd.sku_id and im.barcode = '105683004'
LEFT JOIN pkt_hdr pk 
ON pk.pkt_ctrl_nbr = cd.pkt_ctrl_nbr
where cd.open_cage_batch = 31102014
and pk.to_store IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I learned how to SELECT FROM (SELECT's) here:
[SQL SELECT Union SELECT FROM (Select...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838888/sql-select-union-select-from-select)

In this case, it would be something like...

```
SELECT (columns)
FROM
  (select cd.cage_nbr, cd.units_of_product, pk.to_store
  from cage_dtl cd
  inner join item_master im on im.sku_id=cd.sku_id
  INNER JOIN pkt_hdr pk ON pk.pkt_ctrl_nbr=cd.pkt_ctrl_nbr
  where im.barcode = '105683004'
  and cd.open_cage_batch = 31102014
  ) AS dispatched
JOIN
  (select sd.to_store, sd.alloc_qty, sd.alloc_batch, im.size_desc
  from store_distro sd
  inner join item_master im on im.sku_id=sd.sku_id
  where im.barcode = '105683004'
  and sd.alloc_batch = 31102014
  ) AS allocated
ON (stuff)
```